# Can't get cocoapods to work with Xcode 7.2 beta (7C46t)

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Getting this error

```
ld: framework not found Alamofire
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm trying cocoapods for the first time this morning.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods

pod setup
```

My Podfile looks like this:

```
xcodeproj '/Users/adamek/Development/xCode/Swift_2015/Foody16/Foody16.xcodeproj'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!


pod 'SwiftyDropbox', :git => 'git@github.com:dropbox/SwiftyDropbox.git', :tag => '0.5'
```

`pod install` returns this:

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Alamofire (2.0.2)
Using SwiftyDropbox (0.5)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 2 total pods installed.
```

That part looks good, but I get the following when I try to build my app.

```
ld: framework not found Alamofire
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've also tried `pod repo remove master --verbose` and then `pod install` again, still no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your podfile is not right. I am suggesting you some steps. Carefully follow them

1. sudo gem install cocoapods.
2. pod init
3. open Xcode -a podfile
4. Your podfile should look like this:

---

```
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
pod 'SwiftyDropbox'
pod 'Alamofire'
```

---

5. Save the podfile
6. remove all the local dependencies mentioned in your podfile from target folder.
7. change to #import `<Alamofir/Alamofir.h>`
8. use $inherited in your linker Search Path, Build Settings.
9. Now do pod install, and then pod update.

these steps should resolve your problem. if any other error comes, Comment on this post.